# How many times can two objects moving in a line collide?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, momentum, conservation-laws

Say you have two bodies of mass $m_a$ and $m_b$ moving on a straight line with non-zero velocities then how many times could they collide? My guess is that they'd collide once but how would I prove it mathematically?

Comment: Are there any forces involved in this situation? If not, why on earth would these objects move toward one another, then away from each other, then toward one another again?

Comment: Lol nuclear Wang, does it mean what I think it means cool name :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Choose a frame of reference that is co-moving with the centre of mass. Assuming that the objects are initially located at different positions, either they are static, or they are moving. The former case is not interesting as there won't be any collisions. So assume that we are in the latter case and that the two bodies are set for collision. Since the centre of mass is not moving in the chosen frame of reference, the elastic collision requires that the momentum vectors flip direction. Therefore, after the collision, the two objects will diverge from each other.

Answer (score 0):

From the following explanation from [Walter Lewin's lecture](https://youtu.be/-q-WiX-KVXo?list=PLyQSN7X0ro203puVhQsmCj9qhlFQ-As8e&t=256) on Newtonian Mechanics, a collision is assumed between one moving object (a) with mass $m_a$ and velocity $v_a$ and one stationary object (b) with mass $m_b$ and velocity $0$. Notice how you can rephrase this situation as being a collision between two objects that have a relative velocity difference of $v_a$, because there is no acceleration involved.

The conclusion is that after a completely elastic collision, the velocities of both objects will change like so:

$v_{\text{a,new}} = (\frac{m_a - m_b}{m_a + m_b}) \cdot v_a$

$v_{\text{b,new}} = (\frac{2 \cdot m_a}{m_a + m_b}) \cdot v_a$

If $m_a$ is greater than $m_b$, let's say a bowling ball collides with a football, then the football's velocity will be greater than that of the bowling ball. As they both roll in the same direction, the bowling ball will never catch up with the football and they will never collide again.

If $m_a$ is smaller than $m_b$, so if a football collides with a bowling ball, then the football will bounce away from the bowling ball. As the football and the bowling ball are now moving apart, they will never collide again either.

This means that no matter the velocities, on a flat plane or line, once two objects collide, they will never collide again.